# How to list all Informix database names

Tags: database, informix

I want to know if there is any way to list (get) all the database names on Informix. I need a proper query or stored procedure to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.dmir.doc/dmir69.htm), the command to get a list of the databases on the server you are connected to is simply:

```
show databases
```

Comment: thanks alot,, i wanna to add this link::http://www.informix.com.ua/articles/sysmast/sysmast.htm

Comment: This is not working with Informix version 14.1

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively you could execute this query when connected to the `sysmaster` database:

```
select * from sysdatabases
```

Comment: How to get a list of tables for a specific database when connected using sysmaster user?

Answer (score 6):

More to the point (years after the question was posed):

```sql
select name from sysmaster:sysdatabases;
```

Comment: This is the most precise answer if you want to get the databases listing and works with the most current Informix version (14.1).